# How to Remove/Disable Sign Up From Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I'm trying to remove/disable the `user/sign_up` path from Devise. I'm doing this because I don't want random people gaining access to the application. I have it  partly working by  adding the following in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new" # custom path to login/sign_in
    get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "new_user_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
  end

...

devise_for :users, :skip => :registration

end
```

However, this breaks `<%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-info btn-flat" %>`

which I want to keep so that users can update their profile.
I know it's because of the `devise_for :users, :skip => :registration`

Is there a solution for this issue?

Running

Devise (4.2.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.0)

Rails 4.2.5

ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: You can use `skip: :registerable` and add only the routes you want.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, if I add `skip: :registerable` it will activate `users/sign_up`. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: The devise wiki [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos) is very useful for all sorts of things (I used it to set up my web site to only allow one user)

Comment: It is much easier to completely disable the `registerable` module and write your own controller for user editing with logic you need instead of trying to understand Devise internals and how to override it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Solution to removing sign_up path from Devise**

Enter the following at the beginning of `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new" # custom path to login/sign_in
    get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "new_user_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
  end
```

...After the statement above, add the following below in `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations] 
  as :user do
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end
```

This will remove/disable the `user/sign_up` path for Devise without breaking `edit_user_registration_path`

Restart your rails server and it should work.

Comment: Looks good, but after adding this, `edit_user_registration_path` has begun throwing `NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#edit - undefined method 'validatable?' for nil:NilClass`. I've scoped the views and controllers to accomodate multiple Devise models. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain why the first block is necessary?

Comment: I have same question as @karns. Things seem to work without the first block.

Answer (score 70):

The easiest way is just removing `:registerable` devise module from the default list defined into your Model (the class name used for the application’s users, usually **User**).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ...
end
```

So you'll have it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ...
end
```

Comment: It immediately eliminates the route, it would be nice it it also will skip the registrations folder when creating the views. But you just have to delete that one. And no one can register at the site. That works great with invitable in order to control admin.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't prevent the problem described in the original question. This method breaks `edit_user_registration_path`, stopping users from being able to update their account details.

Comment: Keep in mind, that you also need to tune translation(s), since they still assume you have sign up process. Example: `unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."`

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same issue. My solution is a mix of these answers.

1. Comment out or remove `:registerable` in `user.rb`:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

2. Remove the registration paths from `devise_for` in `routes.rb`:

```rb
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions'
}
```

Now Devise will skip all of the registration links from their view and also you no longer have the registration paths on your routes.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Mainly because it will be forward-compatible. It does not depend on lower level rails code to remove registration abilities.

Answer (score 8):

**Redirecting from controller**

I solved this issue by redirecting /sign_up to /sign_in from the controller, while preserving the functionality of editing user info. For instance:

In controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
# GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
    super
  end
```

In routes.rb, I pointed registrations resource to this controller:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

So whenever users visit route /sign_up, it'll redirect them to /sign_in. Just remember to use `and return` after the redirection to prevent multiple render/redirect

Comment: Went for this in the end. Plus added `:confirmable` just to be on the safe side. Seems like the most straight forward solution indeed.

Comment: I believe you don't need to add  `sessions: 'users/sessions',` inside `routes.rb` since you don't overwrite anything inside.

Comment: I don't recommend this solution. POSTing to /users/sign_up will work.

Comment: @FastDeveloper then maybe do the same for the create method?

Answer (score 5):

Since **[as](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper%3Adevise_scope)** is just an alias for **devise_scope**, you can put all that in just one block.

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
as :user do
  get "/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new" # custom path to login/sign_in
  get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "new_user_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code seem to do the trick for me:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_scope :users do #notice "users" here, not "user"
    get "/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new" # custom path to login/sign_in
    get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "new_user_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
  end

  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end
...
```