# Error disabling sign-ups for Devise model - Devise | Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-routing

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 project with two Devise models (`Admin` and `User`). I've followed the suggestion on this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39780131/5328443) to disable sign-ups for a Devise model without breaking Devise's `edit_admin_registration_path`.

After applying the changes suggested in `routes.rb`, running `rails routes` shows the changes working as expected, however when going to edit an `Admin` (`edit_admin_registration_path`), i get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Admins::RegistrationsController#edit
undefined method `validatable?' for nil:NilClass
```

I suspect the issue is that the linked answer was not using multiple Devise models with scoped views and controllers.

Any ideas?

I've added this to `routes.rb`:

```rb
devise_scope :admin do
  get "/sign_in" => "admins/sessions#new" # custom path to login/sign_in
  get "/sign_up" => "admins/registrations#new", as: "new_admin_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
end

devise_for :admins, skip: [ :registrations ], path: 'admins', controllers: { sessions: 'admins/sessions', registrations: 'admins/registrations' }
  as :admins do
    get 'admins/edit' => 'admins/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_admin_registration'
    put 'admins' => 'admins/registrations#update', as: 'admin_registration'
  end
```

Form on view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), method: :put) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control" %>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer found:

Routes needed to be configured like so (as can be found in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228093/5328443)):

```rb
devise_for :admins, :skip => [:registrations], path: 'admins', controllers: { sessions: 'admins/sessions', registrations: 'admins/registrations' }

devise_scope :admin do
  get 'admins/edit' => 'admins/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_admin_registration'
  put 'admins' => 'admins/registrations#update', as: 'admin_registration'
end
```